# Terraform nested for loops for route association based on tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am new to terraform and I was wondering  in route table association, how can I create association route table subnet associations based on the following criteria:

I have route tables A, B, C
I have subnets D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K
I want route table A to be associated with Subnet D, E
I want route table B to be associated with Subnet F, G, H, I
I want route table C to be associated with Subnet J, K

```
locals {
  route_tables = flatten([
    for route_table_details in aws_route_table.NETWORK-PROD-RT-TEST : [
      for subnet_details in aws_subnet.NETWORK-PROD-SUBNET-TEST : {
       
        ##Pseudo code ###
        if route_table_details.tags.Names == "A" and subnet_details.tags.Names == ("D" or "E"):
          route_table_id = route_table_details.id
          subnet_id = subnet_details.id
        
        elif route_table_details.tags.Names == "B" and subnet_details.tags.Names == ("J" or "K"):
          route_table_id = route_table_details.id
          subnet_id = subnet_details.id
        
         elif route_table_details.tags.Names == "C" and subnet_details.tags.Names == ("F, G, H, I):
           route_table_id = route_table_details.id
           subnet_id = subnet_details.id
        ##Pseudo code ###
}
]
])
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "a" {
  count = length(local.route_tables)
  subnet_id      = local.route_tables[count.index].subnet_id
  route_table_id = local.route_tables[count.index].route_table_id 
}
```

Comment: What is `aws_route_table.NETWORK-PROD-RT-TEST`, `aws_subnet.NETWORK-PROD-SUBNET-TEST`? Do you have example code for them?

Comment: That is basically 3 route tables and 8 subnets in AWS. I cannot share that data here, but they are just names like 
`
resource "aws_route_table" "NETWORK-PROD-RT-TEST" { 
  vpc_id = something
  route {
    cidr_block = "something"
    gateway_id = "something"
    transit_gateway_id  = "something"
    }
  tags = {
    Name = "something"
    Access = "something"
  }
}
`

Comment: Why not create three `local.route_tablesA`, `local.route_tablesB` and `local.route_tablesB` and three corresponding `aws_route_table_association`? It would be much easier to read, debug, modify and maintain then such a complex for loop with multiple conditions?

Comment: As such there are 6 route tables and 16 subnets, the file will get too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your requirements correctly, I think the most straightforward way to write this would be as three separate `aws_route_table_association` resources:

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "a" {
  for_each = {
    for k, v in aws_subnet.NETWORK-PROD-SUBNET-TEST : k => v
    if contains(["D", "E"], v.tags.Name)
  }

  subnet_id      = each.value.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.NETWORK-PROD-RT-TEST["a"]
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "b" {
  for_each = {
    for k, v in aws_subnet.NETWORK-PROD-SUBNET-TEST : k => v
    if contains(["F", "G", "H"], v.tags.Name)
  }

  subnet_id      = each.value.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.NETWORK-PROD-RT-TEST["b"]
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "c" {
  for_each = {
    for k, v in aws_subnet.NETWORK-PROD-SUBNET-TEST : k => v
    if contains(["J", "K"], v.tags.Name)
  }

  subnet_id      = each.value.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.NETWORK-PROD-RT-TEST["c"]
}
```

Each of these uses a `for` expression with an `if` clause to filter out any subnet objects whose names are not in the set of allowed names.

As long as the relationships between the subnets and route tables are arbitrary as they seem here (rather than systematic) I don't think it'll be possible to write a simpler version of this with an intermediate data structure. If there's some system to how the subnets and route tables are connected then I expect you could write expressions that implement that system, but if all you have is a manually-selected list of names for each one then you can't really improve on writing down a list for each of the route tables, in which case it might as well just be three `resource` blocks.

Comment: I did say I have 3 routes, but they come from the same resource

I created 3 dev routes using just one resource statement 
```aws_route_table.DEV-RT```

Thus, I cannot use, aws_route_table.NETWORK-PROD-RT-TEST["c"] 

Is there another way? Possibly with count or something ? 
@martin

Comment: This helped thank you so much. Appreciate it!!

Comment: @VinitaShah question answer did you find for your question about creating 3 routes from the same resource and not using "c". I am running into the same issue.